# Cant load any os installation on laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, operating-systems

So I have downloaded Kali operating system and checked on my main computer (not laptop) if I burned it correctly to the DVD.
The disk was running fine and the os installation showed up.

However, when I tried the same thing with the same DVD disk on my laptop (Asus N550JK) and on restarting the computer choose to boot from "UEFI: MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ8E2 S", you could hear the disk spinning like crazy and the screen turned black (on, but black) and the disk stopped spinning.. I could not get to the OS installation because there was none, just a black screen with no mouse or anything.

My current OS on my laptop is Windows 8.1.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Sounds like the laptop's graphic driver isn't supported by the Kali boot disk. Is there a hotkey option to boot into cmd line mode and specify a generic graphics driver?

Comment: There is none, I managed to get it to work I will add the solution now.

Comment: Goto BIOS and make hard Disk detect as IDE simply by changing the Detect Harddisk as value SATA to IDE then u can install OS..

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work around this problem by using USB.
I have installed the operating system into my USB and tried to boot from there, the system did boot correctly like it should, however the DVD still seem to not work. (The image used is the same as the DVD one)